# How to Create Nested Routes and Indexes in Astro?

Tags: astrojs

I am migrating my Hugo site to Astro. It has nested routes. I am trying to put them in the `pages` folder so that:

`/pages/authors/socrates/republic/book-1/chapter-1.md`

The Authors directory has many authors. Each Author has many books. Each Book has many chapters.

Chapter 1 in the example loads ok. But the problem begins when I go to any `_index.md`.

When I go to any route such as `/authors/` or `/authors/socrates`, it says `404`.

How do I set up the index files so that they show a collection of files in the nested folder?

My only option so far is to manually make an `href` for each `.md` file in the index. This is bad since some folders have hundreds of markdown files.

I tried editing `_index.md`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Astro has a slightly different syntax for index files:

Rename your `_index.md` files to `index.md`.

If you want to list all the articles in the current folder you colud write an index.astro file that uses the `Astro.glob()` functionality. This astro tutorial seems to describe what you want: https://docs.astro.build/en/tutorial/5-astro-api/3/